# Convert Associative arrays into different format

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a associative array like this

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4785
        [courseId] => 1774
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1697
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1775
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1698
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1776
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1699
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1777
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1700
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1778
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1701
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

)
```

I want to convert this associative array like

```
(
4785_1774_13[0] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4785
        [courseId] => 1774
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1697
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

4786_1775_13[1] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1775
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1698
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

4786_1776_13[2] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1776
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1699
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

4786_1777_13[3] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1777
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1700
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

4786_1778_13[4] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 4786
        [courseId] => 1778
        [EnterpriseId] => 13
        [lbaseid] => 1701
        [progress] => 100
        [milestone] => 5
    )

)
```

Comment: _I want..._ is not a valid question for SO. Instead show your attempts and describe issues that you are getting there

Comment: So, what's the problem? Open editor, write code, test it.

Comment: Second array isn't valid php array. `4785_1774_13[0] =>` is invalid

Comment: _small note_ requested array is also not valid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a new array with keys constructed with the values from the original array, you can iterate through the initial array and construct a new array with the desired key format.

```
$array = [
    [
        "userId" => 11,
        "courseId" => 22,
        "EnterpriseId" => 33
    ],

    [
        "userId" => 44,
        "courseId" => 55,
        "EnterpriseId" => 66
    ]
];

var_dump($array);

$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $new_key = implode("_",[
        $value["userId"],
        $value["courseId"],
        $value["EnterpriseId"]
    ]);
    $new_array[$new_key] = $value;
}


var_dump($new_array);
```

Live example here: https://3v4l.org/1ibMl